# Windows Service OnStop() not called

Tags: c#, windows, service

I've written a program in C# that runs as a Windows Service. The application starts up and runs fine, but the OnStop function doesn't get called when I use the Management Console to stop the service.

The OnStart method starts a background thread for the main program, and that background thread starts another thread and a ThreadPool to do work for it.

OnStop I set a boolean flag that all the other threads check in order to see if they should stop processing. The threads should all then finish, and the program should end.

Here's the code for my OnStart

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        mainProgram.IsBackground = true;
        mainProgram.Start();
    }
```

That code works.  Below is the code for OnStop, which as far as I can tell doesn't ever get called.

```
protected override void OnStop()
    {

        Log.LogMessage("Caught shutdown signal from the OS", "debug");
        base.OnStop();
        shutdown = true;
        mainProgram.Join(15000);
        if (mainProgram.IsAlive) mainProgram.Abort();
    }
```

That log message never gets written to the log file.

Any help would be appreciated. I don't even know where to start looking.  Thanks.

**EDIT** 
I solved the problem that was locking the background thread. I also commented out that logging statement, so I know the log statement isn't causing the problem.

I added a ManualResetEvent in addition to the boolean flag. The OnStop now looks like this:

```
protected override void OnStop()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        //Log.LogMessage("Caught shutdown signal from the OS", "debug");
        base.OnStop();
        shutdown = true;
        ShutdownX.Set();  //this is the ManualResetEvent
        mainProgram.Join(15000);
        if (mainProgram.IsAlive) mainProgram.Abort();
    }
```

The place this should stop the code is here in the mainProgram.RunAgent() function (which is its own thread)
     while (!shutdown)
                {

```
                SqlCommand DbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
                DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT id, SourceID, CastingSN, Result FROM db_owner.queue";

                SqlDataReader DbReader = null;
                try
                {
                    DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (DbReader.Read() && !shutdown)
                    {

                        long SourceID = DbReader.GetInt64(1);
                        string CastingSN = DbReader.GetString(2);
                        bool Result = DbReader.GetBoolean(3);

                        WaitCallback callback = new WaitCallback(oComm.RunAgent);
                        CommunicatorState commstate = new CommunicatorState(CastingSN, Result, SourceID);
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback, commstate);
                        callback = null;
                        commstate = null;

                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine("Finished Queueing Threads");
                }
                catch (SqlException Ex)
                {
                    Log.LogMessage("There was an error with a query run on the FlexNet Database.", "error");
                    Log.LogMessage(">> " + Ex.Message, "error");
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (DbReader != null) DbReader.Dispose();
                    DbCommand.Dispose();
                }
                ManualResetEvent[] handles = new ManualResetEvent[2] { eventX, ShutdownX };
                WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles);

                //eventX.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite, true);
            }
```

I *think* this should read from the database, queue up all the threads it finds, then wait for either all the threads to finish processing (the eventX reset event) or the ShutdownX Event.

Once the ShutdownX event is triggered, the outer loop shouldn't continue because the shutdown bool is true, then the thread closes it's SQL connections and should terminate.  None of this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Other than not seeing the message int he log file, what else happens? Is the process killed? Do you get an error in the Services management application? What's written in the Event Log?

Comment: Could one of your other threads be holding a lock on the file that Log.LogMessage is writing to?

Comment: Check to see if the process is hung.  Also, trying running with WinDbg attached, before stopping the service, that way you can check for any exceptions, if the process is being killed instead of stopping gracefully (though Event Log should show evidence of this).  Does your `Log.LogMessage` method have a chance to flush its buffers before the process dies?

Comment: Other than CanStop being false, the typical failure mode here is that your LogMessage() method throws an exception, preventing the rest of the code from running.  Look in the Windows event log for messages.

Comment: I've been playing around with WinDbg, and I think the problem is in some of the background threads.  These threads read values from a database and then transfer them via TCP sockets to another machine that logs them. If I start the service with the database empty the program exits as normal. If the background threads are running doing the data transfer, the program won't respond to the OnStop request.  So I'm going to do a bit more debugging on that section and see if it helps things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `ThreadPool`.  `OnStop` is reportedly never called [until all tasks in the thread pool complete](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/46043/thread-pool-with-windows-service.aspx).  See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644043/stopping-a-multi-threaded-windows-service) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ankur/archive/2005/09/16/469012.aspx).  However, I am leaning towards this not being the main or only cause as some people [seem to be using it with success](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10057143/thread-pool--thread-stop.aspx).

It seems to me that your question currently says that `OnStop` never gets called but that you have seen the log message that it emits.  So I assume that `OnStop` does get called but that some of the threads do not notice that.

Please wrap all code that gets or sets `shutdown` in a `lock` statement, using a single global object.  This is not for atomicity or mutual exclusion.  This is to ensure proper memory barriers on a multiprocessor system.

Comment: It was my understanding that ThreadPool tasks were background tasks and thus wouldn't keep the application from closing, but according to your sources I'm wrong.  I'll have to find another way to manage those threads then.

Comment: @bluesky74656 - Maybe you will not have to; have a look at the updated answer.  If it helps you in any way, I have never seen first hand a pure-C# approach other than `ServiceBase` and `ThreadStart`, often combined with special purpose handlers such as `FileSystemMonitor`.  So that is what would be my first choice if I still believed the referenced `ThreadPool` theory.  (`ServiceBase` does have a few quirks in dealing with services that start or stop extremely slowly.)

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. If the `ThreadPool` is _not_ running, then the main thread and one other thread I create manually get shut down normally, and the service stops. If the `ThreadPool` is running, then I can't get any statement in the OnStop method to run. This makes me think that despite the official documentation that says that all `ThreadPool` threads are background, they are causing OnStop to not run until they are finished. So I think the fix has to be managing my threads manually rather than with ThreadPool.