# Stopping a multi-threaded windows service

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, threadpool

I have a multi-thread windows service in .Net 3.5, and I am having some trouble to stop the service properly when more than one thread is created.

This service used to create only one thread to do all the work, and I just changed it to be multi-threaded. It works perfectly, but when the service is stopped, if more than one thread is being executed, it will hang the service until all the threads are completed.

When the service is started, I create a background thread to handle the main process:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Global variable that is checked by threads to learn if service was stopped
            DeliveryConstant.StopService = false;
            bool SetMaxThreadsResult = ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);

            ThreadStart st = new ThreadStart(StartThreadPool);
            workerThread = new Thread(st);
            workerThread.IsBackground = true;
            serviceStarted = true;
            workerThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log something;
        }
```

Here is the StartThreadPool method:

```
    //Tried with and without this attribute with no success...
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public void StartThreadPool()
    {
        while (serviceStarted)
        {
            ProcessInfo input = new ProcessInfo();

            try
            {
                int? NumPendingRequests = GetItems(50, (Guid?)input.ProcessID);

                if (NumPendingRequests > 0)
                {
                    input.ProcessType = 1;
                    input.ProcessID = Guid.NewGuid();
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(new DispatchManager().ProcessRequestList), input);
                 }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Some Logging here
            }
        }

        DeliveryConstant.StopService = true;
    }
```

I created a static variable in a separated class to notify the threads that the service was stopped. When the value for this variable is true, all threads should stop the main loop (a for each loop):

```
        public static bool StopService;
```

Finally, the OnStop method:

```
protected override void OnStop()
    {
        DeliveryConstant.StopService = true;

        //flag to tell the worker process to stop
        serviceStarted = false;

        workerThread.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }
```

In the ProcessRequestList method, at the end of every foreach, I check for the value of the StopService variable. If true, I break the loop.

Here is the problem:
The threads are created in chunks of 50 items. When I have 50 items or less in the database, only one thread is created, and everything works beautifully.
When I have more than 50 items, multiple threads will be created, and when I try to stop the service, it doesn't stop until all the background threads are completed.

From the logs, I can see that the method OnStop is only executed AFTER all threads are completed.

Any clue what could be changed to fix that?

Comment: Try putting a Sleep(50) in the while loop.

Comment: It seems to me that You haven't included most important part of code. That is ProcessRequestList method implementation.

Comment: Can you show code where StopService is interrogated? Look into using CancellationToken over static var, as it is made for that sort of thing.

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, the ProcessRequestList is not that important, because as I mentioned, the problem is in the variable value change. For some reason, when there are more than one working thread in the threadpool, and the service is stopped, the OnStop method (event) is only called after all threads are completed, meaning that the variable value is not set to true. The ProcessRequestList method is just a foreach loop with a "if(StopService==true) break;" check at the end of the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [blog answer](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/46043/thread-pool-with-windows-service.aspx) states that OnStop isn't called until all ThreadPool tasks complete, which is news to me but would explain your issue.

I've fielded many multi-threaded Windows Services but I prefer to create my own background threads rather than use the ThreadPool since these are long-running threads. I instantiate worker classes and launch their DoWork() method on the thread. I also prefer to use callbacks to the launching class to check for a stop signal and pass status rather than just test against a global variable.

Comment: You nailed precisely the issue. Many thanks! This is pretty much what I said that was going on, but didn't know that it was an expected behaviour. Knowing that, I am now checking the service state in the working threads, and it is working like a charm. Not sure (yet) how costly it will be for performance though. Thanks!

Comment: Roberto, would you mind posting your solution in your question, or is that what the boolean StopService variable is?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing memory barriers around accesses to `StopService`, which may be a problem if you have multiple CPUs.  Better lock any reference object for ALL accesses to the shared variable.  For example:

```
object @lock;

...

lock (@lock)
{
    StopService = true;
}
```

**Edit**: As another answer has revealed, **this issue was not a locking problem**, but I am leaving this answer here as a thing to check with multithread synchronization schemes.

Making the shared variable volatile would work in many cases as well, but it is more complex to prove correct because it does not emit full fences.

Comment: This is not about atomicity but about memory barriers.  Atomicity means that the other thread will see all of it - or none.  Memory barrier (there are two kinds of it in play here, but let's skip that for simplicity) ensures that the "none" case does not happen.

Comment: Oops.  I was jumping between questions.  Rolled back that misedit here.

Comment: I admit that I prefer locks over `volatile` simply because I find their guarantees easier to understand and deduce.  This page has a great example called `IfYouThinkYouUnderstandVolatile`: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

Comment: Jirka, thanks for your comment. The StopService variable is only changed by the main thread (the one adding threads to the threadpool). The working threads only read it. I tried anyway, but it didn't fix the issue. Notice that the variable is changed in the OnStop method, but the OnStop method seems to be called only AFTER all working threads are completed. The only exception is when only one working thread is created in the thread pool. In that case, when the service is stopped, the OnStop event is called right away... Thoughts?!?! Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm happy to see another answer pinning down your issue.  I agree with your analysis now knowing how the ThreadPool behaves.